# How to get the events and holidays occurred on a list of dates?

Tags: date-and-time, wolfram-alpha-queries, scaling

I have a list of 100 unix timestamps and I am trying to get all the events occurred on that time. The following code get an abort signal when a has 100 timestamps. Another problem is that when I run it only for 2 entries it returns value only for the first date:

```
a = Table[{1331789394, 1331089394}];
b = FromUnixTime[#, TimeZone -> -6] & /@ a;
c = DateString /@ b;
WolframAlpha /@ ToString /@ StringJoin[ {"events on "}] /@ c
```

[image]

1. How can I make it work for 100 timestamps?
2. Why when I run it for 2 timestamps I get the same output as if I had only the first element?
3. How to get holidays and other events from wolfram alpha? What is the most general date query?
4. Why if I wolframalpha for holidays he performs so poorly?

Comment: does this give what you need: `Grid[{#, Column@
     WolframAlpha[ "events on " <> #, {{"Result", 1}, "ComputableData"}]} & /@ 
  DateRange["6 march 2012", "13 march 2012", {1, "Day"}]]`?

Comment: Regarding (2), scroll to the right of the window to see the result of the second query (all results are shown in a single line).